# SQL group by multiple categorical columns and count

Tags: sql

I have 3 categorical columns with the same value ranges: 0/1 and NULL.

The columns in SQL:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | NULL | 1 |
| NULL | 0 | 1 |

I want the counts per category like this:

| Categories | Cnt_Col1 | Cnt_Col2 | Cnt_Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| NULL | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Does anybody know how this is possible in SQL? The following query doesn't give the expected result:

Select count(*), column1, column2, column3
from table
group by column1, column2, column3

Comment: What's your dmbs?

Comment: SQL sever management studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to unpivot and then aggregate.  In generic SQL, you can use:

```
select category,
       sum(case when which = 'column1' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_col1,
       sum(case when which = 'column2' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_col2,
       sum(case when which = 'column3' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_col3
from ((select column1 as category, 'column1' as which from t) union all
      (select column2 as category, 'column2' as which from t) union all
      (select column3 as category, 'column3' as which from t) 
     ) c
group by category;
```

In SQL Server, I recommend `APPLY` to unpivot:

```
select v.category,
       sum(case when v.which = 'column1' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_col1,
       sum(case when v.which = 'column2' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_col2,
       sum(case when v.which = 'column3' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_col3
from t cross apply
     (values (column1, 'column1'),
             (column2, 'column2'),
             (column3, 'column3')
     ) v(category, which)
group by v.category;
```